# Multiple Image upload using Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, file-upload

I'm using dynamic input generate function through that I try to upload multiple images upload I got code from the internet and I modified according to my requirement images uploading is working when I the name into the table that time only I'm getting issues.

I can't understand how to do that. Please help how to do that.

I attached my codes, UI, table screenshot.

**Inserting Code**

```
$Colorimages=array();


            if($files=$request->file('Colorimages'))
            {

                foreach($files as $file)
                {
                    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                    $filename = date('YmdHis').rand(1,9999).'.'.$extension;
                    $file->move(public_path("product_images/sub_images"), $filename);
                    $Colorimages[]=$filename;
                }

            }

if(count($request->prol_product_line_code)>0)
        {
            foreach ($request->prol_product_line_code as $prol=>$v)
            {
                $data2=array
                (
                    'prol_product_code' => $request->prod_product_code,
                    'prol_product_line_code' => $request->prol_product_line_code[$prol],
                    'prol_printed' => $request->prod_printed,
                    'prol_color' => $request->prol_color[$prol],
                    'prol_image1' => $Colorimages[$prol],
                    'prol_image2' => $Colorimages[$prol],
                    'prol_image3' => $Colorimages[$prol],
                );
                product_line::insert($data2);
            }
        }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to upload multiple images in laravel.

**Step 1: Create Routes(routes/web.php)**

```
Route::get('image-view','ImageController@index');
Route::post('image-view','ImageController@store');
```

**Step 2: Create ImageController File(app/Http/Controllers/appController.php)**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class ImageController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('image-view');
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $imageName = request()->file->getClientOriginalName();
        request()->file->move(public_path('upload'), $imageName);
        return response()->json(['uploaded' => '/upload/'.$imageName]);
    }
}
```

**Step 3: Create Blade File(resources/views/index.blade.php)**

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-12 col-11 main-section">
                <h1 class="text-center text-danger">File Input Example</h1><br>

                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="file-loading">
                            <input id="file-1" type="file" name="file" multiple class="file" data-overwrite-initial="false" data-min-file-count="2">
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#file-1").fileinput({
            theme: 'fa',
            uploadUrl: "/image-view",
            uploadExtraData: function() {
                return {
                    _token: $("input[name='_token']").val(),
                };
            },
            allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif'],
            overwriteInitial: false,
            maxFileSize:2000,
            maxFilesNum: 10,
            slugCallback: function (filename) {
                return filename.replace('(', '_').replace(']', '_');
            }
        });
    </script>
```